# Integrals in implicit graphs

Tags: calculus, integration, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function

Sorry if my wording is bad and/or this isn't a good question, it's my first time submitting to stackexchange.

As a disclaimer, I'm not a maths student, just interested in some of this during my spare time. I'm currently trying to get a better understanding of implicit curves and calculus.

My question is this:
Graphing $ y^2 = xy - x^2 - x $ results in an ellipse-looking curve, which made me wonder, what is the area enclosed by this shape? I'm not really interested in the answer on its own, what I'm wondering is how one would even begin to approach this sort of problem. With my current level of understanding I'm not even sure how to formulate my question in terms of some kind of integral.

Any clues would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Technically it is just the integral of 1 over that set in 2D. The usual way to calculate this is to write it as some number of double integrals by determining the biggest interval $[a(x),b(x)]$ such that that vertical segment is contained in the domain. For convex shapes each x has just one segment, but a formula for a(x),b(x) may be hard to come by.

Comment: Also, for shapes like this one where the inside is a sublevel set of some real-valued function, it is easy to use Monte Carlo methods to calculate the integral numerically. Let me know if that interests you.

Comment: The first method I mentioned is not really multivariate in character, it is just multivariate in notation.

Comment: Looks like multivariate calculus is needed to really do this, that's good to know! I was planning on looking into that field anyway.